# Gradle - android res location missed

Tags: android, testing, gradle, robolectric

I have following structure of project:

```
src
|-- main
   |-- assets
   |-- java
   |-- res
   |-- AndroidManifest.xml
|-- test
   |-- java
   |-- AndroidManifest.xml
build.gradle
```

Following configuration is set in build.gradle for sources:

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main'
            }
        }
        androidTest{
            java.srcDirs = ['src/test']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main']
        }
    }
```

However when I run the test I tries to load res and assets from src/test/res and src/test/assets instead of location defined in gradle config.

When I copy assets and res resources to test directory, everything works fine, but I don't want to have duplicates of it. Does anyone know how to solve that issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should have these under `androidTest`:

```
res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Still it tries to load resources from incorrect location:

DEBUG: Loading resources for com.testproject from src/test/res...

java.lang.RuntimeException: src/test/res/values is not a directory

Comment: Did you remove `res.srcDirs = ['src/main']`?

Comment: Yes it's removed. Currently I have: 
`androidTest{
    java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
    assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
    resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
}
`

Comment: Does it work if you change it to `resources.srcDir = './src/main/res'`? That's what my ones always have, but the one you have should work.

Comment: Still nothing - I have the same issue

Comment: Hmmm... strange! Possibly a stupid question, but is the `build.gradle` beside the `src` folder in the project structure?

Comment: Yes, build gradle is on the same level as src. I updated the structure of resource to show where the build.gradle is

Comment: Then pass. Sorry. If I happen to get time, I'll set up a project with a similar structure to try it out - because I see no reason why this does not work.

Comment: Try it with just `res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']` instead of `resources.srcDirs` perhaps

Comment: I've already tried with res.srcDirs and resources.srcDirs - still nothing :/

Comment: Wait, your directory tree shows the`build.gradle` inside the `src` directory - is that the case, or a mistake?